# which practise is better? about constructors

Tags: java, oop

Which between of the practises is better, style wise?
using the keyword "this" or choosing a different parameter name for the parameter of the constructor?

case1:

```
public class Student {
  //variables
  private String name;

  //constructor
  public Student(String name) { 
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

or case 2:

```
public class Student {
  //variables
  private String name;

  //constructor
  public Student(String aName) { 
    name = aName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on style and self preferences. It's doesn't affect the performance. I find case 1) as more readable.

Comment: `private.String name;` - how does that even work?

Comment: which is more established then?

Comment: I suspect the answer to this is "whichever way your organisation's coding standards say you should do it". I prefer using `this.`, you just have to double check what you're typing.

Comment: @august what is the point?

Comment: This question is calling for a debate of opinions. There is no "better" here.

Comment: @jDourlens I did a mistake typing private.String name; which kocko edited to private String name; August was right about my misstype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real difference between the two.

I learned to do it with `this` when I started college but when I went to a different school they taught me to do it the second way with different names for the fields. To make it more difficult they even taught me to not do it this way entirely and use setters in the constructor.

I prefer the first way in combination with a setter (so you can check different things or make sure the value is stored the correct way ie a name always starts with a capital)

The way I would do it is the following:

```
public class Student {
  //variables
  private String name;

  //constructor
  public Student(String name) { 
    setName(name);
  }

  //setter
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

But you should choose and use the way you like most, cause you are the one making it.

Comment: Fair enough if you're using setters anyway, but you shouldn't write setter methods just for this purpose.

Comment: This solution demands some additional care. Consider reading articles about calling non-final methods from constructors. One such example: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=20521

Comment: @ATG Even if you want something to be stored the same way? say you have a attribute `private String name;` and you want it to start with a capital as names should start with a capital. The setter is not used atm anywehere except in the constructor of the class to set the name that way. but there's always the possibility that the method is used somewhere when another programmer starts working on it. this way you are certain that the value of name is always stored in the same format.

Comment: @AdrianB. Fair enough, they never taught us the possibility of this happening. Certainly something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Lian de Haas: yes, unfortunately you learn about such problems only later in professional life when either your code is wonky and find out using a debugger or when someone uses such a construction to bypass any restraints you put in the application. Either way, it's useful to know about it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in both the cases. It depends upon your preference. You can do it in any way as you like.

I go with the first method. But I don't have any explanation for selecting that. Because both doesn't have any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" way of doing this. And you'll find people are split between different "schools of thinking" in regards to readability of code.

My advice would be to go with whichever is most used in your organization, or which you consider to be more readable.

I, for one, prefer to use different names for the parameters and also use "this." for the fields, because:

- using the same name can cause minor head aches if you ever forget to use "this."
- using "this." to make it obvious that that is a member field and not a local variable, even outside a color-coded IDE.

Again, this is a personal decision you should make :)

Comment: I think, the standard Java way, as most starters need to grasp the meaning of 'this', is to call `this.attribute = attribute`. On Android, there is another coding policy proposed by Google: private attributes (members) get an 'm'-prefix. For example: `mAttribute = attribute`. But as you said, every company defines its own coding ruleset.

Comment: I am leaning towards the "this" keyword. Seems more natural.

Answer (score 1):

There is a no issue about good and bad. You can choose any way from two which is convenient to you. There is a no difference.
But i prefer case ONE because there is a no need to remember two different variable names for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first one. It can always be used without thinking of new names such as aName. Moreover, this is how, for instance, eclipse generates setters.